# Delay in .net page load accompanied by "Loading Symbols for Microsoft.GeneratedCode" flickering message in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Just seen something today when visiting a site that's driving me made as it rings a bell with something I've seen before and can't quite place.  The symptoms are that a very simple page takes 10 seconds or so to load.

Simple default.aspx page, that inherits a basepage.cs and uses a master page. If a debug point is put on the first line of "page_load" event of master page, then before that line is hit the Visual Studio environment has a flickering message at the bottom of the screen for about 3 or 4 seconds saying, "loading symbols for Microsoft.GeneratedCode" and then it stops at the debug point.

Nothing shows up in Chrome's dev tools network tab prior to aspx page loading.  Wondering what on earth could be happening in the background and where to look - any ideas from my admittedly poor description?

Comment: This is only happening in your dev environment? And probably only on the first page requests?

Comment: No, the delay happens online too. It also seems to happen more than once when the page loads, it's really weird.

Comment: To you have any code executing in your global.asax file on Begin Request?

Comment: Not sure, I'll try and find out as I only saw the code briefly when visiting a location.  Thanks for the input.